# How to make Android Application on Eclipse IDE using Phonegap?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I want to make an Android Application On Eclipse IDE using Phonegap but dont the how to make it and find out online tutorials as well but they are not usefull if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the step by step process. Every step is well explained with possible screenshots. It will help you.
[Eclipse-PhoneGap Tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)

Comment: This link is for phonegap 2.1 which is very very VERY old! Phonegap/Cordova is now in version 3.5 and creating a project is quite different from what it was then. Check newer version : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide And by the way you don't really need eclipse either.

Comment: @QuickFix Have you down voted my answer? May I know the reason? You could suggest the new link.

Comment: Thought my comment is clear enough, your link is about phonegap old 2.1, I provided the link to newest version.

Answer (score 1):

[www.simdroids.com](http://www.simdroids.com)

It has only two posts. both the posts relates to what you are asking